# ant build-service throws 'cannot be resolved to a type' errors

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm using liferay 6.1.1 ce ga2, when I download knowledge base portlet created based on liferay 6.1.x, and run ant build-service, some 'cannot be resolved to a type' errors show up. You can find the complete errors info from the attachment. Even I use the portlet which was installed online through liferay portal and run well , then I copied the installed files from bundled tomcat directory into my portlet directory resided in plugins sdk's portlets and run ant build-service again, errors still showed up.

The funny thing is it was successful time after time yesterday but failed today. The only thing I did today is I setup the portlet development environment based on maven , but I think that had nothing to do with the errors, maven does not change anything of plugin sdk.
  Errors info are as below:

```
Buildfile: M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\build.xml

build-service:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\classes
      [jar] Building MANIFEST-only jar: M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\build-service-classpath.jar
   [delete] Deleting: M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\build-service-classpath.jar.manifest
   [delete] Deleting: M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\build-service-classpath.jar
     [echo] Loading jar:file:/M:/My-Documents/programming/java/lib/Liferay/bundle/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
     [echo] 二月 16, 2013 3:26:55 上午 com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl info
     [echo] INFO: Global shared lib directory /M:/My-Documents/programming/java/lib/Liferay/plugins/lib/
     [echo] 二月 16, 2013 3:26:55 上午 com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl info
     [echo] INFO: Global lib directory /M:/My-Documents/programming/java/lib/Liferay/bundle/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/lib/ext/
     [echo] 二月 16, 2013 3:26:55 上午 com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl info
     [echo] INFO: Portal lib directory /M:/My-Documents/programming/java/lib/Liferay/bundle/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/
     [echo] 二月 16, 2013 3:26:56 上午 com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl info
     [echo] INFO: Properties for portal loaded from [file:/M:/MyLoading jar:file:/M:/My-Documents/programming/java/lib/Liferay/bundle/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-Documents/programming/java/lib/Liferay/bundle/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
     [echo] Loading jar:file:/M:/My-Documents/programming/java/lib/Liferay/bundle/liferay-porta.properties, jar:file:/M:/My-Documents/programming/java/lib/Liferay/bundle/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOl-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/com/liferay/portal/tools/dependencies/portal-tools.properT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/com/liferay/portal/tools/dependencies/portal-tools.properties, jar:file:/M:/My-Documents/programmties
     [echo] Loading file:/M:/My-Documents/programming/java/lib/Liferay/bundle/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/Wing/java/lib/Liferay/bundle/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.propertieEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties
     [echo] s]
     [echo] SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
     [echo] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/M:/My-Documents/programming/java/lib/Liferay/bundle/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/util-java.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
     [echo] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/M:/My-Documents/programming/java/lib/Liferay/plugins/portlets/knowledge-base-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/lib/util-java.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
     [echo] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
     [echo] Building KBArticle
     [echo] Building KBComment
     [echo] Building KBTemplate

compile-java:
    [javac] Compiling 8 source files to M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 1. ERROR in M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\knowledgebase\service\KBArticleService.java (at line 142)
    [javac]     public com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBArticleSearchDisplay getKBArticleSearchDisplay(
    [javac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBArticleSearchDisplay cannot be resolved to a type
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 2. ERROR in M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\knowledgebase\service\KBArticleServiceClp.java (at line 716)
    [javac]     public com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBArticleSearchDisplay getKBArticleSearchDisplay(
    [javac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBArticleSearchDisplay cannot be resolved to a type
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 3. ERROR in M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\knowledgebase\service\KBArticleServiceClp.java (at line 772)
    [javac]     return (com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBArticleSearchDisplay)ClpSerializer.translateOutput(returnObj);
    [javac]             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBArticleSearchDisplay cannot be resolved to a type
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 4. ERROR in M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\knowledgebase\service\KBArticleServiceUtil.java (at line 173)
    [javac]     public static com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBArticleSearchDisplay getKBArticleSearchDisplay(
    [javac]                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBArticleSearchDisplay cannot be resolved to a type
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 5. ERROR in M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\knowledgebase\service\KBArticleServiceUtil.java (at line 181)
    [javac]     .getKBArticleSearchDisplay(groupId, title, content, status,
    [javac]      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] The method getKBArticleSearchDisplay(long, String, String, int, Date, Date, boolean, int[], int, int, OrderByComparator) from the type KBArticleService refers to the missing type KBArticleSearchDisplay
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 6. ERROR in M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\knowledgebase\service\KBArticleServiceWrapper.java (at line 157)
    [javac]     public com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBArticleSearchDisplay getKBArticleSearchDisplay(
    [javac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBArticleSearchDisplay cannot be resolved to a type
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 7. ERROR in M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\knowledgebase\service\KBArticleServiceWrapper.java (at line 164)
    [javac]     return _kbArticleService.getKBArticleSearchDisplay(groupId, title,
    [javac]                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] The method getKBArticleSearchDisplay(long, String, String, int, Date, Date, boolean, int[], int, int, OrderByComparator) from the type KBArticleService refers to the missing type KBArticleSearchDisplay
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 8. ERROR in M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\knowledgebase\service\KBTemplateService.java (at line 100)
    [javac]     public com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBTemplateSearchDisplay getKBTemplateSearchDisplay(
    [javac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBTemplateSearchDisplay cannot be resolved to a type
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 9. ERROR in M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\knowledgebase\service\KBTemplateServiceClp.java (at line 335)
    [javac]     public com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBTemplateSearchDisplay getKBTemplateSearchDisplay(
    [javac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBTemplateSearchDisplay cannot be resolved to a type
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 10. ERROR in M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\knowledgebase\service\KBTemplateServiceClp.java (at line 389)
    [javac]     return (com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBTemplateSearchDisplay)ClpSerializer.translateOutput(returnObj);
    [javac]             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBTemplateSearchDisplay cannot be resolved to a type
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 11. ERROR in M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\knowledgebase\service\KBTemplateServiceUtil.java (at line 108)
    [javac]     public static com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBTemplateSearchDisplay getKBTemplateSearchDisplay(
    [javac]                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBTemplateSearchDisplay cannot be resolved to a type
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 12. ERROR in M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\knowledgebase\service\KBTemplateServiceUtil.java (at line 116)
    [javac]     .getKBTemplateSearchDisplay(groupId, title, content,
    [javac]      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] The method getKBTemplateSearchDisplay(long, String, String, Date, Date, boolean, int[], int, int, OrderByComparator) from the type KBTemplateService refers to the missing type KBTemplateSearchDisplay
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 13. ERROR in M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\knowledgebase\service\KBTemplateServiceWrapper.java (at line 101)
    [javac]     public com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBTemplateSearchDisplay getKBTemplateSearchDisplay(
    [javac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] com.liferay.knowledgebase.model.KBTemplateSearchDisplay cannot be resolved to a type
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 14. ERROR in M:\My-Documents\programming\java\lib\Liferay\plugins\portlets\knowledge-base-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\knowledgebase\service\KBTemplateServiceWrapper.java (at line 108)
    [javac]     return _kbTemplateService.getKBTemplateSearchDisplay(groupId, title,
    [javac]                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] The method getKBTemplateSearchDisplay(long, String, String, Date, Date, boolean, int[], int, int, OrderByComparator) from the type KBTemplateService refers to the missing type KBTemplateSearchDisplay
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 14 problems (14 errors)
```

build.fxbird.properties is as below,fxbird is os login user.

```
app.server.dir = M:\\My-Documents\\programming\\java\\lib\\Liferay\\bundle\\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\\tomcat-7.0.27
java.compiler = modern
app.server.lib.global.dir = M:\\My-Documents\\programming\\java\\lib\\Liferay\\bundle\\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\\tomcat-7.0.27\\lib\\ext
app.server.type = tomcat
app.server.deploy.dir = M:\\My-Documents\\programming\\java\\lib\\Liferay\\bundle\\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\\tomcat-7.0.27\\webapps
app.server.portal.dir = M:\\My-Documents\\programming\\java\\lib\\Liferay\\bundle\\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\\tomcat-7.0.27\\webapps\\ROOT
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in service folder.Please delete the service folder path (WEB-INF\service) and also classes folder path (WEB-INF\classes) and run build service again.

Comment: I did it several times before posting the thread and it did not work. I think now that's because of the dismatching between source code and sdk plugins.

Comment: hey u got solved your error..because i have same problem..please help me if u got solution